# Android listview with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I'm creating an application that will basically pull data from an SQLite database and show up a `ListView` using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`

My problem is when using the 
`setOnItemClickListener` it does not work at all.

Here is the `onCreate` event on my Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria);
    //Mostrando lista
    dbcon = new SQLController(this);
    dbcon.open();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Cursor cursor = dbcon.readData();
    String[] from = new String[] { DBhelper.MEMBER_ID, DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tv_descripcion, R.id.tv_Titulo };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Categoria.this,
            R.layout.fila, cursor, from, to);               
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    //Fin de mostrar lista
    Log.d("jose", "Salio del Adapter");
    //Click en el elemento de la lista
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.d("jose", "Toco la lista"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tocado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    });     



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple actually. to work you just have to add a single line in the xml where describle row. In botonoes xml property is added

android: focusable = "false"

and problem solved. Since the setOnItemClick funsiona listview